# How to Enable/Disable "Press and Hold" right click in Win7 from Command Prompt

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen

How can I enable & disable the option of "Press and Hold" for a right click in Windows 7 from the command prompt?

Comment: I have never used this feature: How is it enabled normally? Maybe if I can see that, I can figure it out.

Comment: It's for a stylus, if you hold the tip to the screen for a length of time it acts as a right click.

Comment: Is it enabled in Windows, or some other program? If in windows, where exactly is it enabled?

Comment: Its a windows feature in control panel, when you have a touch screen